# Is it safe for C# camera frame event to update a pictureBox? I'm getting intermittant error: "System.Drawing.dll .. Parameter is not valid."

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, picturebox

Or, should pictureBox only be updated by the UI thread?

I assign event callback to my Accord VideoCaptureDevice class, which gets live frames from my USB camera.  About 10 frames per second.
In the event callback, I update a pictureBox with the latest live frame.

I'm trying to figure out why I get this intermittent error...
"… An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Parameter is not valid."

CODE THAT STARTS CAMERA FRAME EVENT...

```
// Automatically start inputing each frame from camera:
var videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
// Select physical USB camera:                 http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Video_DirectShow_VideoCaptureDevice.htm
videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice( videoDevices[0].MonikerString, pixelFormat_for_ExhaustiveTemplateMatching);

Console.WriteLine( "BOOT: PixelFormat = " + pixelFormat_for_ExhaustiveTemplateMatching.ToString() );

// Select event handlers:
videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler( EVENT_camera_frame ); //http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Video_NewFrameEventArgs.htm

// Start slurpin up them camera frames:
videoSource.Start();
```

EVENT CODE THAT GETS FRAME, DRAWS BOX ON IT, AND DISPLAYS PICTUREBOX...

```
            if( latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap != null )
            {
                latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Dispose();
            }

        // Convert from camera native pixel format to comparison compatible format:
                 latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap = new Bitmap(   camera_frame_Bitmap.Width, 
                                                            camera_frame_Bitmap.Height,
                                                            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage( latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap)) 
        {
            gr.DrawImage( camera_frame_Bitmap, new Rectangle(   0, 0, 
                                                                latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Width, 
                                                                latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Height));
            // Apply user specified angle of rotation:
                switch( image_rotation_degrees )
                {
                    case 0:     latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.RotateFlip( RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone ); break;
                    case 90:        latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.RotateFlip( RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone );   break;
                    case 180:       latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.RotateFlip( RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone );  break;
                    case 270:       latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.RotateFlip( RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone );  break;
                }


            Rectangle crop_rectangle = new Rectangle( 0,0,0,0);
            get_crop_rectangle( PictureBox_live_camera.Width, 
                                PictureBox_live_camera.Height,  
                                ref crop_rectangle );       //   latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap  ==>  crop_rectangle X, Y, Width, Height


            if( Computer_Vision_API.reference_cropped_Bitmap != null )
            {
                Computer_Vision_API.reference_cropped_Bitmap.Dispose();
            }
            Computer_Vision_API.reference_cropped_Bitmap = new Bitmap(  Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap );

            Computer_Vision_API.reference_cropped_Bitmap = Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Clone(    crop_rectangle,
                                                                            Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.PixelFormat);


            pictureBox_reference_snapshot.Image = Computer_Vision_API.reference_cropped_Bitmap;  


            // Draw crop rectangle in Live Camera View:
                Graphics live_image_Graphics = Graphics.FromImage( latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap ) ;
                live_image_Graphics.DrawRectangle( crop_pen, crop_display_rectangle );   /////////////   DRAW CROPPING RECTANGLE   /////////////
                live_image_Graphics.Dispose();




        // Show crosshairs, if requested in camera view:

            // Create pen.
            Pen crosshairs_pen = new Pen(Color.White, 1 );

            int width = Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Width;
            int height = Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Height;

            int top_y = height - 1;
            int bottom_y = 0;
            int left_x = 0;
            int right_x = width - 1;

            // Create points that define line.
            Point crosshair_point_top = new Point( width / 2, top_y );
            Point crosshair_point_bottom = new Point( width / 2, bottom_y );
            Point crosshair_point_left = new Point( 0, height / 2 );
            Point crosshair_point_right = new Point( width-1, height / 2 );

            float[] dashValues = { 4, 2 };
            crosshairs_pen.DashPattern = dashValues;
            // Verticle crosshair:
            Graphics live_image_Graphics = Graphics.FromImage( Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap );
            live_image_Graphics.DrawLine( crosshairs_pen, crosshair_point_top, crosshair_point_bottom );

            // Horizontal crosshair:
            live_image_Graphics.DrawLine( crosshairs_pen,  crosshair_point_left, crosshair_point_right );
            live_image_Graphics.Dispose();

        // Display latest frame from camera:
            PictureBox_live_camera.Image = Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap;
            PictureBox_live_camera.BackgroundImage = Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap;
```

}   // END OF 'using'

END OF EVENT

Comment: “Or, should pictureBox only be updated by the UI thread?” Yes, UI stuff must be done on the UI thread.

Comment: How should I do that?  Use a timer object? 1ms period is plenty fast.